# Reconstrução 3D MATLAB

Tags: imagem, matlab, processamento-de-imagens, 3d

Estou desenvolvendo meu TFG com MatLab onde a partir de uma figura em Imagem superior 20X20 e uma figura Inferior tbm 20x20 eu gero o possível miolo em outras N imagens centrais. Porem para apresentar o resultado preciso usar essas imagens para gerar minha figura 3d.

Alguém sabe como posso fazer isso?

Exemplo: minha imagem superior e um círculo desenhado em uma imagem 20x20. Já minha imagem inferior é um quadrado em uma imagem tbm 20x20. As imagens centrais são geradas de acordo com suas limitantes sup e inf. Como se eu disparasse as limitantes ao mesmo para se encontrarem no centro. Assim tenho 9 novas imagens q são resultado da mescla dessa sup e inf. O meu problema é q depois disso tudo eu preciso gerar essa imagem final em 3D. Pois tenho essa figura fatiada em 11 pedaços. Uma maneira mais simples seria vc pensar q tem um tubo de mortadela fatiado em 11 pedaços. E no fim preciso mostrar q isso e um tubo de mortadela.

Comment: Oi Paulo. Eu creio que facilitaria um bocado se você publicasse os valores de exemplo de cada matriz 20x20 que você tem das camadas. Assim, alguém interessado em te ajudar não precisa ficar criando nada manualmente. :)

Comment: Este material da documentação do MatLab pode lhe ser de alguma ajuda: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/techniques-for-visualizing-scalar-volume-data.html

Comment: @LuizVieira por serem matrizes 20x20 não consigo posta-las aqui. O senhor poderia me dizer como faço isso?

rsrsr Desculpe a pergunta Idiota

Comment: Seria bem pior se fossem matrizes de 200x200. :) Você pode colocar arquivos texto ou mesmo as imagens (em formato jpg, png, etc) com o conteúdo das matrizes em algum site de armazenamento (Dropbox, Rapidshare, etc), e então postar o link na pergunta.

Comment: @LuizVieira com o documento que você me enviou consegui fazer as reconstruções Obrigado!!

Porem agora identifiquei dois probleminhas, quem sabe você não consegue me dar outra luz. 

1) Na reconstrução estou realizando apenas  o contorno, não estando preenchida a imagem por dentro. 

2) O resultado final esta sendo apresentado sem nenhum contorno, o que deixa certas visualizações muito confusas. 

No link estou enviando a função e meus resultados, caso possa me ajudar

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1usa04a0s3glyw0/AAC2voKXgf1fyFioiQs6XNX2a?dl=0

OBRIGADO

Comment: Oi Paulo. O SOPT *não é um fórum*, e sim um site de perguntas e respostas. Se você conseguiu resolver esta parte da sua dúvida, sugiro que você mesmo poste uma resposta explicando como o fez (pra servir de ajuda pra outras pessoas no futuro) e *abra outra pergunta* com um assunto diferente. Se por acaso o seu problema continua o mesmo mas você tem mais detalhes, edite a pergunta para melhorá-la. Considere também construir um [exemplo mínimo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para incluir na pergunta e facilitar a vida de quem vai te ajudar. :)